# Adding items at the end/start of RecyclerView using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

```
cmdr= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cmdr);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(InterR.this);
        mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);         

Query q= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("com").orderByChild("id").equalTo(idrc.getText().toString());

                mAdapter4 = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Cmd,mViewHolder>(Cmd.class,R.layout.item_cmd_r,mViewHolder.class,
                        q) {


                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(mViewHolder viewHolder, Cmd model, int position) {

                        if(this.getRef(position).getKey()!=null)
                        {viewHolder.idc.setText(this.getRef(position).getKey());}


                        if(model.getAddress()!=null)
                        {viewHolder.adc.setText(model.getAdresse());}

                    }

                };
            mAdapter4.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver()
            {


                @Override
                public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int ItemCount){
                    super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart,ItemCount);
                    int roomCount = mAdapter4.getItemCount();
                    int lastVisiblePosition = mLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                    if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 || (positionStart >= (roomCount -1) && lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart -1))){
                        cmdr.scrollToPosition(positionStart);
                    }

                }
            });

            cmdr.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            cmdr.setAdapter(mAdapter4);
```

I'm trying to populate a RecyclerView with data retrieved by FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, it's working but the problem is whenever an item is added, instead of showing at the end of the list or at the top, the item is inserted in the same position as it is in the database

Answer (score 0):

Inside the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter declaration, override the getItem() function.

```
    @Override
public User getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(getItemCount() - 1 - position);
}
```

Credit to https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/310#issuecomment-247816246